# Labeling points with numbers in a Graphics expression

Tags: graphics

Can I label points with numbers in my Graphics expression, as in this picture

[image]

Here is my code.

```
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]

{α, γ, ω} = {0.1, 0.05, 1};

T = (2 π)/ω;

a = NDSolve[{x''[t] - γ (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + x[t] == α Cos[ω t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
      {x, x', ω t}, {t, 0, 700}];

ss[n_] := Table[x[t T] /. a, {t, 0, 100 T}][[n, 1]];

ff[n_] := Table[x'[t T] /. a, {t, 0, 100 T}][[n, 1]];

g1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], x'[t]} /. a], {t, 0, 100 T}];

g2 = Graphics[Table[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{ss[n], ff[n]}]}, {n, 1, 20}]];

Show[{g1, g2}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]

{\[Alpha], \[Gamma], \[Omega]} = {0.1, 0.05, 1};

T = (2 \[Pi])/\[Omega];

a = NDSolve[{x''[t] - \[Gamma] (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + 
      x[t] == \[Alpha] Cos[\[Omega] t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x, 
    x', \[Omega] t}, {t, 0, 700}];

ss[n_] := Table[x[t T] /. a, {t, 0, 100 T}][[n, 1]];

ff[n_] := Table[x'[t T] /. a, {t, 0, 100 T}][[n, 1]];

g1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], x'[t]} /. a], {t, 0, 100 T}];

g2 = Graphics[Table[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{ss[n], ff[n]}]}, {n, 1, 20}]];

g3 = Graphics@Table[Text[Style[n, 20], {ss[n] + 0.2, ff[n]}], {n, 1, 20}];

Show[{g1, g2, g3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could add some `TextLabels` to your plot:

```
labels = Range[10];
randomPoints = Table[{Random[], Random[]}, {n, 1, 10}];
Show[
Graphics[Table[Text[t, randomPoints[[t]], {2, 0}], {t, 1, 10}]],
Graphics[Table[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[randomPoints[[t]]]}, {t, 1, 10}]]
]
```